# Change specific object values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I need to change the `fuelType` and `mode` independently in each of the separate stations but I cant figure out how, I can print the array but can't figure out changing its contents

```
station = new Pumps [10];

    station[0] = new Pumps(" P101", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[1] = new Pumps(" P102", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[2] = new Pumps(" P103", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[3] = new Pumps(" P104", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[4] = new Pumps(" P105", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[5] = new Pumps(" P201", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[6] = new Pumps(" P202", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[7] = new Pumps(" P203", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[8] = new Pumps(" P204", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[9] = new Pumps(" P205", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

The user needs to find the station by its ID which is eg. P101, then change each value that says
Idle and Default

This is my object class:

```java
public class Pumps {

    private String pumpID;
    private String mode;
    private String fuelType;
    private double total;
    private double pumpOutPut;
    private double pumpInTake;


    //Constructor
    public Pumps ( String pumpID, String mode, String fuelType, double total ,
                  double pumpOutPut, double pumpInTake){
        this.pumpID = pumpID;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.fuelType = fuelType;
        this.total = total;
        this.pumpOutPut = pumpOutPut;
        this.pumpInTake = pumpInTake;

    }
    //*************Pump-ID*********************
    public String getPumpID() {
        return pumpID;
    }

    public void setPumpID(String pumpID) {
        this.pumpID = pumpID;
    }




    //*************MODE*********************

    public void setMode(String newMode) {
        this.mode = newMode;
    }



    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    //*************FUEL-TYPE*********************

    public void setFuelType(String newFuelType) {
        this.fuelType = newFuelType;
    }

    public String getFuelType() {
        return fuelType;
    }
    //*************PUMP-IN-TAKE*********************


    public void setPumpInTake(double pumpInTake) {
        this.pumpInTake = pumpInTake;
    }


    //**************PUMP-OUT-PUT********************
    public void setPumpOutPut(double pumpOutPut) {
        this.pumpOutPut = pumpOutPut;
    }

    //*************TOTAL*********************

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a `Map<String, Pump>`, not an array, and your `mode` and `fuelType` values should be enums.

Comment: im a student , and apparently I have to use an array or array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the array of Pumps and search for specific element once you found it change the property you need

```
        for (int i = 0; i < station.length; i++) {
            if (" P101".equals(station[i].getPumpID())) {
                station[i].setMode("newMode");
                station[i].setFuelType("newFuelType");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are welcome :), https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers